# Managed C++ ref class

Tags: managed-c++, ref

Any good site or explanation on what is a `ref class` and when to declare a class to be a "ref class"?

The explanation on msdn wasn't enough for me,

> **base_type(optional)**
>
> A base type. A ref class or ref struct can inherit from zero or more managed interfaces and zero or one ref types. A value class or value struct can only inherit from zero or more managed interfaces.
>
> **ref**
>
> The `ref` keyword tells the compiler that the class or structure will be allocated on the heap and a reference to it will be passed to functions or stored in class members. The `value` keyword tells the compiler that all of the data in the class or structure is passed to functions or stored in members.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Basically, a `ref class` is a CLR class.  It's the equivalent of `class` in C#.

This creates a reference type managed by the CLR.  If you want to make a class that's usable from C#, you'd normally create a `ref class`.  (`ref struct`, by the way, does exactly the same thing, but with C++'s standard class vs. struct default accessibility rules.)

Also, just for reference - in order to make a value type (`struct` in C#), you'd use `value class` or `value struct`.

A good explanation of many of these new keywords is [Herb Sutter's post on C++/CLI Keywords](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/hsutter/archive/2003/11/23/53519.aspx).  This is a useful reference if you're new to C++/CLI, but have a solid C++ background.

Comment: Nicely explained the basic concept. Thank you! that's exactly what I was looking for :)

Comment: wayback machine link: https://web.archive.org/web/20150409152850/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/hsutter/archive/2003/11/23/53519.aspx