# Visual studio 2022 VC++ class wizard new class has a managed option

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++-cli, managed

I am using visual studio 2022 with c++, and I wanted to use the class wizard feature to add a class, when I noticed that in the add class menu there is an unselectable option titled "Managed".

I wanted to ask if anyone knows what it is, is it related to C++/CLI? Does it show up even if I do not have it installed?

Comment: The option shows up anyway (disabled).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create a CLR Project you will find that you could select managed.

[image]

It will create a managed class. I suggest you refer to this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4684365/managed-c-ref-class) about ref class.

[image]

If you want to try to create a CLR Project you need to install C++/CLI Support in the visual studio installer.